# Pass by reference/value overload

Tags: c++, reference, overloading

Trying to figure out why no overloading-ambiguity caused in the following codes:

```
float foo2(float& i)
{
    cout << "call from reference" << endl;
    return i;
}
float foo2(float i)
{
    cout << "call from non reference"<<endl;
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<foo2(2); // print "call from non reference"
}
```

The foo2 whose parameters not passed by reference is called. Why? How to call the foo2 that pass reference parameters?

Comment: _"How to call the foo2 that pass reference parameters?"_ Give it a reference?

Comment: [The compiler will complain about ambiguity](http://ideone.com/W5eLdq) if you're trying to use the ambigous call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `2` you gave as a parameter for `foo2` is an rvalue, which cannot be a reference. Thus the function accepting a reference cannot be called with it.

Comment: `2` is not an rvalue reference, it's an rvalue. It can *bind* to an rvalue reference. (The code in the question doesn't exhibit ambiguity, you would have to change the first function to `const int&` t ocreate ambiguity.)

Answer (score 8):

> The `foo2` whose parameters *not* passed by reference is called. Why?

Because you cannot pass a constant or any computed expression by reference to a function that takes a non-constant reference. To pass an expression by reference you need an assignable value - something that can appear on the left-hand side of an assignment expression. Since `2` cannot appear on the left side of an assignment expression, it cannot be used to call a function that expects a reference. When the reference is `const`, you can pass anything, because C++ will create a temporary variable, assign the expression to it, and pass a reference to function taking `const` reference.

> How to call the `foo2` that pass reference parameters?

There is no obvious way of doing that, because the moment you pass a variable or another expression that can become a reference, the compiler will complain that you are making an ambiguous call:

```
float f;
foo2(f); // <<== This will not compile
```

There is a way to call it, though: you can make a function pointer that matches only one of the two function signatures, and use it to make your call:

```
typedef float (*fptr_with_ref)(float&);

int main()
{
    cout<<foo2(2) << endl; // print "call from non reference"
    fptr_with_ref foo2ptr(foo2); // Only one overload matches
    float n = 10;
    cout<<foo2ptr(n) << endl; // Calls foo2(float&)
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/9VyOLL)

Comment: Interestingly, `int f; foo2(f);` will compile and result in a call to the non-reference function (just tried it out). Though I cannot say why. (**Edit** reverted an edit because @dasblinkenlight answered below, thanks)

Comment: @jadhachem Because the compiler makes a call like this: `foo2((float)f)`. Since `f` needs to be converted from `int` to `float`, there is no ambiguity. If you make `f` a `float`, you would see the ambiguity.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, thanks for your answer. Concept cleared. Your answer didn't appear before i refresh the page.

Comment: There is mention like *When the reference is const, you can pass anything, because C++ will create a temporary variable, assign the expression to it,* Can you kindly give a bit more clarity ?- Does that mean a copy constructor will be invoked for creating temporary?. I tried a sample and copy constructor wasn't invoked.

Comment: @Kiran Could you please share a sample? You can put it on ideone.

Comment: @Kiran There is no need to make a copy in your example, because variable `a` can be used directly. It would be hard to catch a copy inside the call, though, because C++ aggressively optimizes them out when it can. For example, [here](http://ideone.com/0Ipboi) it drops the copy constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is in C++ terms, not in design terms. C++ supports things in a way because it makes sense in terms of design. C++ allows you to do a lot of things, but if you want to make good software with it you cannot stick to mere literal C++ rules, you need to go further. In practice that means you end up making your own rules.

In your case - well, I'd never make the reference variant if I did not actually change the variable in the function.

If you adopt such 'rules' for yourself, then you immediately see why the ref function doesn't bind: what is the point, in the first place, to change a loose constant?

If you make the right rules, you'll see that they are beautifully supported by C++. Like ... function changes an object: pass non-const ref. No change? const ref. Optional? const pointer. Take over mem management? non-const pointer.

Note that that is just the beginning, especially when multi-threading comes into play. You have to add things to the 'contract' of the function. Example for const ref: must the object stay 'alive' after the call? Can the object change during the call? And so forth.